# AJAX and DOM function malfunction

Tags: javascript, ajax

attempting to call a method for creating a display container for the

```
xmlhttp.responseText;//createDisplayElement()
```

In the following:
[JS BIN Document](http://jsbin.com/utumif/13/edit)

No Errors to the Error console in FF, but the behavior is off, not refreshing the page properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues in the code.

1. `obj` is not defined properly.
2. plain text (`xmlhttp.responseText`) is appended to a `p` element.

Both of them are corrected below.

Try this,

```
function makerequest(serverPage, objID)
{

    xmlhttp.open("GET", serverPage);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

        if(xmlhttp.status == 200 || xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

            createDisplayElement(objID);
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function createDisplayElement(objID){
    var obj = document.getElementById(objID);
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    obj.appendChild(para);
    var txtNode = document.createTextNode(xmlhttp.responseText);
    para.appendChild(txtNode);

}
```

Comment: After implementing the suggestion, the HTML is loaded with literal interpretation. All the HTML elements are printed.

Comment: Please be specific. Are you returning HTML from your ajax call? If so,you can do para.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText

Comment: Yes, the files are HTML snippets, but I'm hoping to avoid innerHTML, this the reason for the inquiry

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `obj` may be improperly defined in context of the function.   Try `this` instead:

```
// It is called as:
obj.createDisplayElement(); 


// But the function also uses obj
function createDisplayElement(){

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    this.appendChild(para);
  //^^^^^^  
    var txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
    para.appendChild(txt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function lacks a reference to `obj`

```
function createDisplayElement(){

    var para = document.createElement("p");
    obj.appendChild(para);
    var txt = xmlhttp.responseText;
    para.appendChild(txt);

}
```